# ASP.NET MVC Dependency Injection Error:Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5

I need too add a Service to my Asp.net MVC5 web application
I use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection library
and I'm using default ApplicationDbContext
it works until I have only one request from Controller otherwise I get this Error: System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.

my code : 
Startup.cs:

```
 var services = new ServiceCollection();
        service.AddMyService(); // I need to inject this library
        services.AddScoped<HomeController>();
        services.AddScoped<RenderController>();
        // Build the container while ensuring scopes are validated
        ServiceProvider container = services.BuildServiceProvider(true);

        // Replace default controller factory
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(
            new MsDiControllerFactory(container));

        ConfigureAuth(app);
```

MsDiControllerFactory.cs

```
public class MsDiControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly ServiceProvider container;

    public MsDiControllerFactory(ServiceProvider container) => this.container = container;

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext c, Type type) =>
        (IController)this.GetScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(type);

    public override void ReleaseController(IController c) => this.GetScope().Dispose();

    private IServiceScope GetScope() =>
       (IServiceScope)HttpContext.Current.Items["scope"] ??
          (IServiceScope)(HttpContext.Current.Items["scope"] = this.container.CreateScope());
}
```

some code of my usage:

```
private ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext();
 public ActionResult RenderMobileMenu()
    {
        var productGrp = _db.ProductGroups.AsNoTracking().Where(p => !p.IsDeleted).ToList();

        return PartialView("_PartialMobileMenu", productGrp);
    }
 public ActionResult RenderMenu()
    {
        var productGrp = _db.ProductGroups.AsNoTracking().Where(p => !p.IsDeleted).ToList();

        return PartialView("_PartialMenu", productGrp);
    }
```

in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("RenderMenu", "Render", new { Area = "" }); }
@{ Html.RenderAction("RenderMobileMenu", "Render", new { Area = "" }); }
```

I tried AoutoFac but after using that Login and Register didn't work.

please help me how to solve this problem,
oR,
if it is possible tell me other way to inject my Service

Comment: Generally speaking, a global (to the controller) DbContext is a bad idea. You probably want to use a new context per request, wrapping the context in a using statement.

Comment: thanks for replying, but how can I implement wrapping the context?!

Comment: if you mean this code below that it doesn't work:
using (DBContext context = new DBContext())
{
  ..
}

Comment: Also I tried using UnitOfWork but that Error still Exists

Comment: Check the `GetScope()` method? Do you always have value in `HttpContext.Current.Items["scope"]`?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct way to use a DbContext. What "doesn't work"?

Comment: @Tieson T, I meant The Error Still Exists :Cannot access a disposed object

Comment: @Rahatur Yes always It has value